# can i use for statement in .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, indentation

```
GridLayout:
    cols:
    rows: root.numberoflist

    for i in range(root.businfolist): 
        Label:
            font_name: 'C:/Windows/Fonts/HYWULM'
            text_size: cm(2), cm(2)
            pos: self.pos
            id: my_custom_label
            text: root.businfolist[0]
            color: [255,255,255,1]
```

.kv file

i want use FOR STATEMENT to .kv file and i saw the

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html?highlight=statement

this page, but i don't understand.

i think indentation seems to be wrong. 
what is wrong with these code?

traceback is here thank you for read my question.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/TubucTest.py", line 58, in <module>
     class Bus_Information(Screen):
   File "C:/Users/mg/Desktop/Tubuc/TubucTest.py", line 60, in Bus_Information
     Builder.load_string(f.read())
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 368, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 392, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 501, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 605, in parse_level
     level + 1, lines[i:], spaces)
   File "C:\Users\mg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 615, in parse_level
     'Invalid property name')
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 28:
 ...
      26:       rows: root.numberoflist
      27:       
 >>   28:       for i in range(root.businfolist): 
      29:           Label:
      30:               font_name: 'C:/Windows/Fonts/HYWULM'
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

Comment: I would highly recommend keeping all of your logic in your Python script, and reserve your .kv file for UI structure and layout.

Comment: could you tell me the reason?

Comment: One of the main advantages to kv is having the ability to separate the logic of your application from the user interface. Your logic should reside with your class definitions, and be tied to the methods that those classes possess. kv is merely a means of structuring your UI to leverage the power of those classes. It looks from your question that you want to create many Labels in a GridLayout, this is easily achieved from the Python side. Just create widgets in a for loop there, seeing as your `businfolist` variable already resides there.

Comment: @rahlf23 
I agree with your comment on the advantage of the interface and the logic but in the code of the question points out the creation of the interface, not the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add import statement, `#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label`
2. Use `on_parent` event to execute the for loop in kv file

[Valid expressions](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords)

> There are ***two places that accept python statements in a kv file***:
>   ***after a property***, which assigns to the property the result of the expression (such as the text of a button as shown above) and
>   ***after a on_property***, which executes the statement when the property is updated (such as on_state).

## main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label

GridLayout:
    cols: 3
    on_parent:
        for i in range(10): txt = "Label {0}".format(i); self.add_widget(Label(text = txt, text_size=(cm(2), cm(2)), pos=self.pos,
        id=txt, color=(1,1,1,1)))
'''))
```

## Output

[image: Img01]

Comment: I think your answer is correct, I just have a curiosity, why `on_parent`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, according to the Kivy Language manual: `There are two places that accept python statements in a kv file: after a property, which assigns to the property the result of the expression (such as the text of a button as shown above) and after a on_property, which executes the statement when the property is updated (such as on_state).`

Comment: @JohnAnderson I understand the `on_property`, but my question goes in the sense of why exactly use the `parent` property?